# Can I upload Wordpress-react theme in Wp theme repository

Tags: theme-development, themes, wordpress.org

I am planning to create 1 open-source react theme using wp-api and I want to upload it in Wp theme repository. I have referred Upload theme guidelines, and I noticed my theme will not meet couple of required items like [Language](https://make.wordpress.org/themes/handbook/review/required/#language) & [Templates](https://make.wordpress.org/themes/handbook/review/required/#templates). Will my theme be eligible to be uploaded on repository?

Comment: why do you ask here instead of just asking the theme review team?

Answer (score -1):

Your theme may not be eligible to be uploaded to WordPress repo due to the required items *(just as you rightly pointed out)*.

Though you can create a WP theme using React.js [see example](https://ustwo.com/) and [source code](https://github.com/ustwo/ustwo.com-frontend), but you'll have to meet all the requirements before your theme is eligible.

Comment: please, wanting to help is very nice thing, but the idea is that answer represent authoritative opinion, not a guess, and it is unlikely that you have an authoritative knowledge on the issue  unless you are member of the theme review team. I personally don't see any problems with those two sections, a wordpress JS app kind of theme can be developed and answer to those conditions, or the TRT might make an exception due to the call to move to JS based development